# How to account for direction of wave propagation in the wave function?

Tags: waves

The wave function (this is the wave function in mechanical waves. It is **not** the wave equation, which is derived from this wave function. Neither is this the wave function for quantum mechanics!) is given as: 
\begin{align}
y(x,t)&=A\cos(kx \pm \omega t + \phi) 
\end{align}
*(where $k$ is the wavenumber, $x$ is the position, $A$ is the amplitude, $\omega$ is the angular frequency, $t$ is the time, and $\phi$ is the phase difference)*

From my knowledge, the $\pm$ in front of $\omega t$ is to account for wave direction. However, mathematically, I am unable to intuitively understand or even picture why this $\pm$ sign in front of $\omega t$ (which accounts for the time dependency of the wave function) should account for direction. Hence, may I know the connection between this $\pm$ sign and the direction of the wave propagation? Thank you!

Comment: Hint: Solve for the positions of crests and troughs in an $(x,t)$ diagram.

Comment: To clarify, I should calculate the number of crests and troughs? Or should I solve for something else, if so, what exactly?

Comment: @LucasTan you should calculate positions of the crests and how these positions depend on time.

Comment: That isn't the wave function. That is just a possible solution to the wave equation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to determine the direction of a wave propagation?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/56338/)

Comment: @BioPhysicist thank you for sharing that post! For some reason when I tried to find my question on stack exchange, I didn't find this post, it was really helpful. To summarise my new understanding, if we follow a section of a wave that is moving, its phase must remain constant, hence the expression within the cosine must remain constant. As x decreases, time must increase, if x moves in the opposite direction (i.e. increases), time must decrease. Hence we put the plusminus sign in front of the time term to ensure the phase is constant. Could I clarify that my current understanding is accurate?